# Problem with recalculating route too often

Tags: ios, geolocation, here-api

We are using Here SDK for native iOS App. We are testing application in US, and while driving on the highway, application attempts to recalculate when near every highway exit or access road even though we stayed on the highway. Probably this is connected with GPS inaccuracy. Probably position manager thinks that we are not on highway but on highway access road. We found in documentation that setting "mapMatchingEnabled" to true should help but it didn't. We checked Here Maps application and looks that it works better.

This is how we use Here SDK:

```
let dataSource = NMADevicePositionSource()
dataSource.setPositioningMethod(.GPS)

let manager = NMAPositioningManager.sharedInstance()
manager.dataSource = devicePositionSource
manager.mapMatchMode = .car
manager.mapMatchingEnabled = true
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The map matching is automatically enabled during navigation and there are different causes for map matching errors.
One of them is insufficient map data because of a sketchy GPS position. You can pre-fetch the map data along the route using NMAMapDataPrefetcher.fetchMapDataForRoute before navigation is started.
Antother possibility is that you can enable the enhanced map matcher - NMAApplicationContext.enableEnhancedMapMatcher